# exporting a typescript variable with its type information

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a certain config variable with an interface.

```
//I declare my interface

interface ServerConfiguration {
  development: {
    db: {
      url: string,
      user: string,
      password: string,
    },
    webServer: {
      port: number;
      rootPath: string;
    }
  };
}

//I declare a variable that uses that interface

const config: ServerConfiguration = {
  development: {
    db: {
      url: "someUrl",
      user: "myuser",
      password: "mypassword",
    },
    webServer: {
      port: process.env.PORT || 9001,
      rootPath: rootPath,
    },
  },
};
// I export my variable
export  {config};
```

after that i import it and try to create a function that is designed to consume that configuration

```
// I import my variable
import  config  = require( "./config");


// I create a function that will consume a variable that complies with that interface
function initializeDatabase(config: ServerConfiguration) {
//do stuff
}
```

Here i get the error "cannot find name 'ServerConfiguration'", what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here i get the error "cannot find name 'ServerConfiguration'", what's wrong?

- Export each thing individually

  ```
  export interface ServerConfiguration {
  // also 
  export const config: ServerConfiguration = {
  ```
- and import it

  ```
  import  {config,ServerConfiguration} from "./config";
  ```

Comment: You build my IDE, fix my github issues, write my typescript manual and now answer my stackoverflow questions.
Are you some kind of internet god or something?, maybe i should print your picture and put it next to some candles.

Anyways, thanks!!! you are awesome!!

Comment: Just a guy who loves TypeScript and helping people. People like you make it all worth it 